# Completing one array of mongoose requests before beginning another with Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I am creating two arrays of promises using forEach loops. I need the first request to FULLY complete before the second begins. However, when I examine my log I see that the "first" and "second" messages are not appearing in the proper order, even though I thought I configured the promises so that they would. Help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
function saveInstance(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        var saveInstances = [];
        dateStarts.forEach(dateStart=>{
            var trimmedDate = siteBody.substr(dateStart+dateNeedle.length, 400).trim();
            var trimmedDateArray = trimmedDate.split(',');
            var instanceId = trimmedDateArray[0].substr(7,6);
            titleRecords.findOne({"titleByDate.instanceId": instanceId}, function(err,data){
                if (err) throw err;
                if (!data & trimmedDateTime !=null){
                    var instancerecord = new titleRecords();
                    instancerecord.titleByDate.instanceId      = instanceId;
                    instancerecord.newTitle                    = 1;
                    saveInstances.push(instancerecord.save(function(err,data){
                    console.log('This should print first');
                    err ? reject(): resolve();
                }));
                }               
            })
        })  
    Promise.all(saveInstances).then(updateInstanceTime,reject); 
    })
}

function updateInstanceTime(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        var updateInstanceTimes = [];
        dateStarts.forEach(dateStart=>{
            var trimmedDate = siteBody.substr(dateStart+dateNeedle.length, 400).trim();
            var trimmedDateArray = trimmedDate.split(',');
            var titleTitle = trimmedDateArray[1].substr(2, trimmedDateArray[1].trim().length-2);
            var instanceId = trimmedDateArray[0].substr(7,6);

            var conditions      = {'titleByDate.instanceId'  : instanceId};
            var update          = {'titleByDate.lastSeen': localISOTime };
            updateInstanceTimes.push(titleRecords.update(conditions, update,function(err,data){
                console.log('This should print second');
                (err) ? reject() : resolve();
            }));
        })
    Promise.all(updateInstanceTimes).then(resolve,reject);  
    })
}

saveInstance();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is hard to reason about because are you mixing node-callbacks and promises. If you are using promises stick with it.

1. Usually you don't need to manually create a Promise. It is well known "Forgotten promise" [anti-pattern](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/)
2. Use promisified versions of methods do not mix callback with Promises.
3. `!data & trimmedDateTime !=null` & - is bitwise and operator. I believe you want `&&`
4. Do not use `forEach` to create another array with transformed items. There is `map` for that.

Here is an example of how you could rewrite first function. You should do the same for the second one.

```
function saveInstance() {
  return Promise.all(
    dateStarts.map(dateStart => {
      var trimmedDate = siteBody.substr(dateStart + dateNeedle.length, 400).trim();
      var trimmedDateArray = trimmedDate.split(',');
      var instanceId = trimmedDateArray[0].substr(7, 6);

      return titleRecords.findOne({
          "titleByDate.instanceId": instanceId
        })
        .exec()
        .then(data => {
          if (!data) {
            var instancerecord = new titleRecords();
            instancerecord.titleByDate.instanceId = instanceId;
            instancerecord.newTitle = 1;

            return instancerecord.save()
          }
          return data
        })
    })
  ).then(updateInstanceTime)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. That was an interesting article about the "Forgotten Promise" -- I did not know about that. Can you help me figure out how to promisify the console.log callbacks so that I can test that this is running in the right order?

Comment: @garson Simple way would be to define a tap function `const tap = result => (console.log(result), result)` And then use with whatever promise you like. For example `return instancerecord.save().then(tap)`